# Filter URL's with regular expressions in php

Tags: php, regex

What I'm trying to do is to block any kind of url and links posted on my site,
The thing is that these people started posting these links like that for example:

```
W/W/W.DOMAIN.C/O/M
W//W//W//.DOMAIN.C//O//M
```

They are using many different variations, and I don't know what to do in order to block them all.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using a spam-checking service like [akismet](http://akismet.com/) and incorporate that into your site. It will help you catch spam like that.

This way, you wont have to struggle with regex.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I still am very curious about how to block this kind of spam with regex